# How to handle time events on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, date, timer

I'm coding an iPad app, and I have to change a graphic when the day changes to Sunday.

My straightforward solution is to check the day in the `- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application` or `-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` methods, and set a timer like every 10 mins to check if the day have changed to Sunday while the app is active.

Is there another, perhaps more efficient, way to handle this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your appliciation delegate, implement the following method:
`-(void)applicationSignificantTimeChange:(UIApplication *)application`

This method is called when the day changes, or if the device's time has been changed in the background for whatever reason (such as changes to time zone).

Answer (score 4):

Another option would be to use the same two methods you mentioned, "viewWillAppear:" and "applicationDidBecomeActive:" and instead of setting a timer for every 10 minutes, just calculate the amount of time between the current time and the next Sunday.  Take that time interval and use it to set a timer that will fire exactly at midnight on Sunday.

Answer (score 1):

There's a notification for when the day changes. You could listen to it and check if it's sunday when it fires.

You should also check if it's sunday at launch.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with that solution? Does it become Sunday more frequently than once every 10 minutes in some places?

One thing you might want to consider: in your timer fire method, if the time is after 23:50 then reschedule the timer for sooner (i.e. around 00:00) so you're more likely to catch midnight accurately.

Comment: I just don't like the idea of having a timer asking for the date every some amount of time, I Feel kind of dirty ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This chapter might prove useful, using some type of Notification to update:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW1

Although I myself ended up with the same solution you are using, it's just easier and more reliable I find.

Comment: Why you think is more reliable?

Comment: It seems like there are issues when the device goes into deep sleep.  I think you might need to register for remote notifications to get this to work correctly...  strange that Apple doesn't seem to have a proper solution for this, Android has great support for this sort of thing.