# applicationSignificantTimeChange not being fired

Tags: ios

I have placed the following code in my appdelegate, but it has not being called. Any idea(s)?

```
 - (void)applicationSignificantTimeChange:(UIApplication *)application
        {

    NSData *data =[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"walking_coordinate"];
    NSMutableArray *walking_array = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];

    NSData *data1 =[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"driving_coordinate"];
    NSMutableArray *driving_array = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data1];

    NSData *data2 =[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"biking_coordinate"];
    NSMutableArray *biking_array = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data2];

    [walking_array removeAllObjects];
    [driving_array removeAllObjects];
    [biking_array removeAllObjects];


}
```

Comment: should it have been called? Why do you expect it being called? There is not much information in your question, consider rephrasing it.

Comment: Have a look at :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20327348/understanding-applicationsignificanttimechange.

Comment: "This method is called when the day changes", but it did not.

Comment: @casillas :: his answer makes sense. if it is killed and launched again, this isn't called. So... is applicationDidFinishLaunching called again due to your app being closed?

Comment: @casillas :: Also.. you are aware this doesn't do ANYTHING as you write nothing back

Comment: @Daij-Djan,I put this code in my appdelegate, this should be called when the day changes? am i wrong?

Comment: only if your app is running